# Issue With Value Comparison in Sort

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, conditional-statements

I'm playing with ArrayList class methods and such in a separate .java file as I continue to work on a highscores feature. Now, it suits my purposes to have two equal scores arranged such that the first instance of score n(no equals before it if it is the first score anyways) remains higher on the list than the second instance of score n. I've gotten two of my sort methods to work, yet it always skips over any section of the loop where I try to use an == comparison. I'm setting the values manually a la "test"(see code). The code is below, if any of it seems hard to understand feel free to mention it. Debugging stuff is commented out.

```
import java.util.*;

   public class arraylisttest 
   {    
        public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    ArrayList<Integer> grn = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println("Empty:");
    for (int i = 0; i < grn.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Key" + i + " : " + grn.get(i));
    }
    grn.add(122);
    grn.add(534);
    grn.add(132);
    grn.add(310);
    grn.add(267);
    grn.add(322);
    System.out.println("Full:");
    for (int i = 0; i < grn.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Key" + i + " : " + grn.get(i));
    }
    int myscore = 534;
    Integer test = myscore;//reassignment, not entirely necessary
    int y = 0;
    Collections.sort(grn);

    System.out.println("Sorted: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < grn.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Key" + i + " : " + grn.get(i));
    }

    //fix sort so that number is added correctly if equal to last element
    int max = grn.size();

    if(test > grn.get(y))
    {
        if(test < grn.get(max - 1))
        {
            System.out.println("bigger, sm max");
            grn.set(y, test);//in at 0
            y++;//now 1
            while (grn.get(y) < test)
            {
                grn.set(y-1, grn.get(y));//shift this one down
                grn.set(y, test);//fill the hole
                y++;//ends up at 5
            }
        }

        else if(test > grn.get(max-1))
        {
            System.out.println("bigger, gr max");
            int temp = grn.get(max-1);
            grn.set(max-1, test);//in at end
            y++;
            while(y < (max-1))
            {
                grn.set(y-1, grn.get(y));//shift this one down
                grn.set(y, grn.get(y+1));//fill the hole
                y++;//ends up at 5
            }
            grn.set(max-2, temp);
        }

        else if(test == grn.get(max-1))//error here
        {
            System.out.println("bigger, eq max");
            y++;//now 1
            while (grn.get(y) < test)
            {
                grn.set(y-1, grn.get(y));
                grn.set(y, test);
                y++;
            }
            grn.set(y-1, test);
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Oops.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("too small");
    }
    //end sort

    //System.out.println("Test: " + test);
    //System.out.println("Myscore: " +myscore);

    System.out.println("Sort" + y + " : ");
    for (int i = 0; i < grn.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Key" + i + " : " + grn.get(i));
    }
```

Note that the first two sorts work as intended so far as I can tell.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? There's probably a better way than with what you are trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java `Integer` is a class. To compare the values of two objects you need to use `.equals` otherwise you're comparing if they are the same object (which means the same reference in memory).

Comment: :3 I asked the same sort of question about a String object and had the false impression I could compare ints this way. It works now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above the classes are compared with the .equals() function, and your test variable is clearly not a primitive type...

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation of equals tests for identity rather than for equality (indeed, the answer to the question of "what constitutes equality for an object?" can become a rather complex discussion), i.e. objecta.equals(objectb) is defined by default as objecta == objectb which is true only if these reference the exact same instance.

The reason that Strings can be compared out of the box with sa.equals(sb) is because an implementation for equals() has been provided that establishes equality when character sequences are identical.  Implementations for equals() are never provided for classes that you roll.

What this means is that when you decide to use your own objects in the Collections framework, and then use features or methods that depend upon an implementation of equals(), you run into problems because a==b is almost never what you want.

TL;DR: To make the fullest use of the Collections Framework with your own objects, you must define and implement equals(), hashcode(), and often the Comparable interface.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the reason you are trying to do sorting manually is that you want to make sure that whoever got a score first will be listed first in case of a tie. There is a better way of doing this - store the data in a custom object, and use `Collections.sort()` with a comparator.

For example:

```
public class HighScore {
    public int score
    public String name
    public long timestamp

    public HighScore(int score, String name, long timestamp) {
        this.score = score;
        this.name = name;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

When you create it, use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get the timestamp. Then when you are sorting them, use this:

```
Collections.sort(grn, new Comparator<HighScore>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Highscore h1, Highscore h2) {
        if (h1.score == h2.score) {
            return h1.timestamp < h2.timestamp ? -1 : 1;
        } else {
            return h2.score - h1.score;
        }
    });
```

This way you only need to call `grn.add()` followed by the called to `Collections.sort()`

Comment: Also, I'm not confident that I got the compare method right, but you should be able to understand the general idea